# What should happen when the return value from a C++ function that returns a reference of an undefined object type is not assigned?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following code:

```
class Foo;

Foo& CreateFoo();


void Bar()
{
   CreateFoo();
}
```

In Visual Studio this will result in an error C2027 that Foo is an undefined type. In most other compilers it compiles fine. It is only an issue if the return value of CreateFoo is not assigned. If I change the line to:

```
Foo& foo = CreateFoo();
```

it compiles fine in Visual Studio. Also if Foo is defined rather than just forward-declared, then it will compile fine with no assignment.

Which should be the correct behavior? Is there anything in the C++ standard that addresses this, or is this something that is left to the implementation? I looked and didn't see anything that talks about this.

Update:
[A bug report has been filed.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/757831/)

Comment: Which version of the Visual C++ compiler?  Compliance changes pretty dramatically between versions.

Comment: This looks like a Visual C++ compiler bug (I agree with Ben Voigt's analysis of the specification, and the difference in behavior between `CreateFoo();` and `Foo& foo = CreateFoo();` is weird).  I don't see an existing bug for this issue, and it does repro with Visual C++ 2012.  If the issue is important to you, please consider opening a bug on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/) and posting a link here for future reference.  Thank you!

Comment: There was a bug report filed on it for VS2010, but it was marked nofix because it was a documented limitation. They didn't proffer an opinion as to whether it was compliant or not. The MSDN page for C2027 in VS2010 shows the same type of issue. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c2dk0ah.aspx See the last section. It actually says references to undefined types are not allowed, but that is not true, it only appears to be when it is unassigned return values, which is the case in their example code.

Comment: @Gerald : Would you mind posting a link to the VS2010 bug report?

Comment: Sorry, I was apparently very confused there. I did NOT see a bug report for this for VS2010, it was an MSDN thread with a Moderator named "nobugz" that pointed out that it was a documented limitation. And it was for VS2005 :/ Not sure what convolution of events made me think it was a bug report for 2010. I was looking at a lot of bug reports today I guess. But the bug remains. I will go ahead and file a bug report for 2012 on this.

FWIW, this is the MSDN thread:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vclanguage/thread/02aaef70-8a92-4f65-8c15-7b866d5d19d2

Comment: I have filed a bug report and updated the question with the link.

Comment: Try this with the reference you initialized: `foo;`. Does that give an error? If so, the reason probably is that the compiler does an lvalue to rvalue conversion (read: it tries to read the value of what the reference refers to), thereby requiring the definition of the type.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb - That makes sense and was my first thought. And it does indeed give me an error when I just do foo; However, if it was doing an lvalue to rvalue conversion, shouldn't it also fail if Foo was a defined type that is abstract? That does not produce an error.

Comment: @gerald good point. perhaps they were trying to be compatible to C, which always does the lvalue to rvalue conversion. and they applied some checks that made them only do it for c pods?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb - not sure but that wouldn't surprise me. It seems to be an issue that goes back to at least Visual Studio 2005, well before Microsoft started displaying much concern about standards. So my guess is it was the result of some kind of hack in the legacy compiler code that they just never thought was important enough to deal with.

Comment: nobugz posts here as [@HansPassant](http://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/), maybe he knows something we don't, so here's hoping this lures him here. ;-]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like the relevant part of the Standard (section 5.2.2):

> A function call is an lvalue if the result type is an lvalue reference type or an rvalue reference to function
>   type, an xvalue if the result type is an rvalue reference to object type, and a prvalue otherwise.
>
> If a function call is a prvalue of object type:
>
> - if the function call is either
>
>   - the operand of a *decltype-specifier* or
>   - the right operand of a comma operator that is the operand of a *decltype-specifier*,
>
>   a temporary object is not introduced for the prvalue.  The type of the prvalue may be incomplete.
>     [ Note: as a result, storage is not allocated for the prvalue and it is not destroyed; thus, a class type is
>     not instantiated as a result of being the type of a function call in this context. This is true regardless of
>     whether the expression uses function call notation or operator notation (13.3.1.2).  — end note ] [ Note:
>     unlike the rule for a decltype-specifier that considers whether an id-expression is parenthesized (7.1.6.2),
>     parentheses have no special meaning in this context.  — end note ]
> - otherwise, the type of the prvalue shall be complete.

Since this function result type is an lvalue reference type, the function call evaluates to an lvalue, and the completeness requirement does not apply.

The code is legal, at least in C++11, which no released version of Visual C++ implements fully.

Comment: Thanks, that's about what I thought but couldn't pin it down.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use incomplete types in function declarations (since that only declares a signature of the function, not any real code), but not when you use it.

Calling `CreateFoo();` is equals to `(void) CreateFoo();`, and my guess is that Visual Studio needs to inspect the code of Foo to do ANY conversion (I'm not sure if you can actually write a void conversion), because, for conversions you need a complete type.

As for `Foo & foo = CreateFoo();`, this does not do any conversions, so you can get away with having an incomplete type.

Comment: Thanks, that does shine a little light on why VS doesn't handle it. Doing Foo& foo = CreateFoo(); (void)foo; results in the same error. This would seem to indicate that it is indeed a non-compliance issue, since the standard states: "Any expression can be explicitly converted to type cv void, in which case it becomes a discarded-value expression".